# como parsear datos angularjs

Tags: angularjs, post

resulta que hago esta peticion en el controllers a mi php:

```
  $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/nPanelarencion/app/php/consulta.php',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      'Accept': 'application/json' 
  },
```

})

la cual en consola me muestra sus datos de la siguiente manera

[image: datos]

Esos mismos datos necesito guardarlos en `$scope` para poder usarlos en html...

Controller code:

```js
 app.controller('search', function($timeout, $scope, $http) {

//     comienza la  conexion

getInfo();

function getInfo(){

  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/nPanelarencion/app/php/consulta.php',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', /*or whatever type is relevant */
          'Accept': 'application/json' /* ditto */
      },
      data: {
       /* You probably need to send some data if you plan to log in */
   }
  })

.success(function(data){

    console.log(data);
    localStorage.setItem("Tickets", angular.fromJson(data));


//NEXT>

       $scope.loadUsers = function() {
         return $timeout(function() {
           $scope.tickets = localStorage.getItem('Tickets');

         }, 650);
       };
})};
```

```
conection.php:
```

```html
<?php
// Connecting to database as mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "database name");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "saltala");
?>
```

consulta.php:

```html
<?php

// Including database connections
require_once 'conection.php';
// mysqli query to fetch all data from database
$query = "SELECT rut, numero, servicio_id FROM Tickets";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$arr = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$arr[] = $row;
 }
}
// Return json array containing data from the databasecon
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);
?>
```

PREGUNTO: ¿Como lo hago? he intentado parsearlo y todo pero aún no me sale.

necesito mostrar los rut en un select

```
      <md-select placeholder="Assign to user" ng-model="buscar" md-on-open="loadUsers()" style="min-width: 200px;">
    <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="tick in tickets | filter : buscar" >{{tick.rut}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

Comment: cual es el error?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Te aparece algún error en la consola? ¿No se muestran los datos en la vista?

Comment: ninguno, solo que no he podido mostrarlos, he intentado parsearlos de muchas maneras pero no he dado con ninguna.

Comment: Creo que s por que son promesas, por decirlo asi

Comment: Necesito mostrar los datos en el html, quiero mostrar todos los rut en un select...

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo javascript que usas para esto, quizas se el problema

Comment: Hernan puedes dejar en el codigo EL JSON por favor...

Comment: puse el codigo entero

Comment: Tienes el codigo PHP que hace ese JSON? quizas por ahi se esta haciendo dificil el tema

Comment: ya lo he subido.

Comment: has tratado de hacer un `console.log()` apuntando a un objeto en especifico

Comment: si, me sale underfined    intente con un console.log(response.data.rut); , console.log(JSON.stringfly(response.data.rut));  y lo mismo, con JSON.parse sale un error de posicion.

Comment: @HernanHumaña podrias imprimir el "data" que recibes cuando haces el post a tu archivo.php por favor.. es muy confuso el orden de tu array..

Comment: en seco es el de la imagen....

Comment: console.log(data);

Comment: No puedo copiarlo desde la imagen amigo! al menos enviame unos 2 o 3 datos de ese arreglo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema no tiene que ver con AngularJS. Las funciones[`localStorage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) y [`localStorage.setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) manipulan cadenas de caracteres

> Un DOMString que contiene el valor de la clave. Si la clave no existe, devuelve null.

Lo que debes hacer es

```
$scope.loadUsers = function() {
     return $timeout(function() {

         $scope.tickets = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Tickets'));
         ....
```

para convertir la cadena de nuevo a objeto y

```
.success(function(data){

    localStorage.setItem("Tickets", JSON.stringify(data));
    ......
```

al guardar dichos valores.

Lee [¿Cómo puedo convertir un string JSON a un objeto en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1648/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-convertir-un-string-json-a-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: lanza este error : angular.js:13920 ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Debes escribir eso en el success de tu llamada a tu archivo.php

Comment: Tienes razón @sioesi. De hecho debería cambiar el `success` por `then` ya que este es obsoleto.

Comment: Claro!, se ha visto harto que success ya esta obsoleto! @devconcept

Comment: @devconcept puedes echar un ojo a mi respuesta? Creo que tambien es una opcion valida! tengo dudas sobre cuando recibo un JSON, volver a parsearlo

Comment: @sioesi El objeto recibido en data puede renderizarse y recorrerse ya que es de hecho un objeto válido (siempre y cuando use `json_encode` en el servidor lo cual ya está haciendo) pero no hay necesidad de recorrerlo ya que esa tarea la hace automáticamente `ng-repeat` en la vista

Answer (score 1):

Solucione el problema anterior, ahora que tengo los datos, los quiero guardar en LocalStorage pero me sobreescríbe los datos, dejándome sólo uno...

Cómo guardo los datos? en el controlador, quedando así:

```
    $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/nPanelarencion/app/php/consulta.php',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})

  .then(function(data) {
     var dat = data.data;

     for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
       dat[i]
      var runum = dat[i].rut +","+ dat[i].numero
      console.log("show: ",runum);
      localStorage.setItem("rutnum",runum);
     }
  });
```

y  `console.log(runum)` ahora muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, Como recibo los datos?, bueno en otro controlador, en la funcion siguiente:

```
      function loadAll() {
    var rut = localStorage.getItem("rutnum").split(",")[0];
    console.log("el rut es: ",JSON.stringify(rut));


    var num = localStorage.getItem("rutnum").split(",")[1];
    console.log("El numero es: ",parseInt(num));
    var finalnum = parseInt(num)

    var repos = [
      {
        'rut'      : rut,
        'numero'   : finalnum

      }

    ];
    return repos.map( function (repo) {
      repo.value = repo.rut.toLowerCase();
      return repo;
    });
  }
```

y como dije anteriormente el resultado es que solo me muestra un solo rut y un solo numero, entiendo que sobre escribe el anterior, como hago para guardar todos los rut?

Esta es la imagen del LocalStorage y lo que me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT SIOESI**

El error esta en la siguiente linea :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
      var runum = dat[i].rut +","+ dat[i].numero
      console.log("show: ",runum);
      localStorage.setItem("rutnum",runum);
 }
```

Tu estas recorriendo tu arreglo y guardando 1 por 1 EL MISMO NOMBRE DE LA KEY DE TU LOCALSTORAGE.. por eso siempre queda el ultimo Debes hacer algo asi

```
var tickets = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
    var ticket = {id : dat[i].id, rut : dat[i].rut};
    tickets.push(ticket);
}
localStorage.setItem("Tickets",tickets);
```

Entonces, creas un tipo de objeto del arreglo que tiene `id` y `rut`, lo agregas en el arreglo `tickets` y luego guardar en `localStorage` el arreglo Tickets.. Ese arreglo tickets lo llamas desde tu controlador

```
$scope.tickets = localStorage.getItem('Tickets');
```

Y ahora puedes recorrerlos

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
    {{ticket.rut}}
</div>
```

Comment: angular.js:13920 ReferenceError: i is not defined error

Comment: @HernanHumaña i esta definido en el for, no deberia dar ese error. De todas formas, la mejor respuesta a tu caso es la de devconcept

Comment: @HernanHumaña no entiendo tu problema ahora...

Comment: @HernanHumaña voy editar ya encontre el error

Comment: en  LocalStorage me guarda solo un solo rut y  no todos los rut...

Comment: @HernanHumaña edite mi respuesta dice EDIT SIOESI, ahi te explico tu problema...

Comment: me funciono pero lo tube que parsear ya que salía [obj][obj]

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47195/discussion-between-sioesi-and-hernan-humana).

Comment: Hernan eso iba a pasar porque yo hice un objeto con id y con rut, tu mostrabas un string con tu rut y concatenando el id.

Comment: Ahora jaja estoy intentando implementarlo en un autocomplete de angularjs-material y me muestra solo 1 dato, de echo el mismo rut y numero que el del post  una joda... jajaja

Comment: Es que realmente tu no tienes claro que hacer, no cambias la pregunta y haces cambios sin avisar asi es imposible darte una respuesta concreta. Imposible.

Comment: ire mejorando eso, sorry . y a tí te agradezco un monton