# ¿Como puedo pasar un objeto javascript a cadena de string?

Tags: javascript, string, objeto

Tengo un objeto en `Javascript` con diferentes atributos, alguno de ellos son `arrays`.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna función de alguna clase estilo .`toString()` para que me devuelva una cadena de texto con todos los datos.

Ejemplo:

```
let partida = {
  usuarioCreador: "..",
  estado: "..",
  jugadores: [...],
  ..
  }

//cadena de texto deseada
let salida = "[ "propAtributo1","propAtributo2",["propiedadesAtributo 3"],"propAtributoN" ]";
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo convertir un string JSON a un objeto en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1648/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-convertir-un-string-json-a-un-objeto-en-javascript)

Comment: @Mariano Realmente creo que no sería duplicado ya que en esta pregunta es un objeto que quiere pasar a string y en la otra es un string que quiere pasar a objeto.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Sé que pregunta lo contrario. Pero fijate la respuesta. No sólo da la solución de `JSON.stringify`, sino que ayuda a explicar la diferencia entre objeto y JSON, que muchos se confunden

Answer (score 2):

```js
/* Ejemplo */
 var obj=
 {
    UsuarioCreador:"Javier",
    Codigo:"090F",
    Tema:"JavaScript"
 };
 
 /* stringify convierte el objeto 'obj' a una cadena JSON */
 console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
 console.log(typeof (JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

Comment: Hola Javier, ¿podrías elaborar un poco mas tu respuesta?

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! es justo lo que andaba buscando